# Display workspace's number?

Tags: 10.10, workspaces

is there a way to somehow display the number (or identifier) of the current workspace in ubuntu 10.10?

Comment: (2 hours since the questiion was asked) ... It surprises me that the answer is considered good (+4) but then ignore the question (0) ... there would be no "good" answer without a "good" question to provoke the answer.. so +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Indicator-Workspaces](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/indicator-workspaces-adds-options-maverick-ppa-plus-hints-at-future-features/):

[image]
<sup>Screenshot from [omgubuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/the-omg-guide-to-must-have-indicator-applets/)</sup>

Comment: Is this able to run in 10.04? .. I've treid the PPA install and the .deb install.. and nothing shows up in the panel... The only way I could get it to do something was to run the python script directly. but no numeral appeared on the panel icon (path?)... It's a nice compact indicator (if I can get it to work...

Comment: I just noticed the "10.10" reference in the question.. Well that goes some way towards explaing why it doesn't work for my 10.04, and yet it does work for my VM 10.10.. so the answer suits the question well...